# Why SOLR does not search 0 in text?

Tags: 7, search

When user enter to searchbox "0", it is showed all results (likes when you submit empty searchbox). It's work like search remove "0" from search keys. Is it SOLR or drupal problem? How to avoid this?

**update**

```
<?php 
function hook_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface &$query) {
  if ($_GET['search_textfield_value'] === '0') {
    $keys = $query->getKeys();
    $keys[] = '+0';
    $query->keys($keys);
  }
}
```

If add this code, it will work. But why?)

Comment: All results have likely got a zero in them somewhere, I imagine SOLR is just returning what you've searched for

Comment: no, I have few nodes and only one contein 0 in text

Comment: So you're not indexing (for example) the created date of the node? That will contain zeroes, any other field or property that you're indexing may also. Or maybe it's a bug in drupal solr/solr itself. Just trying to rule out the obvious

Comment: I created page by views, added search filter, which looks only in title and body.

Comment: I thought all the search apis required 3 or more characters to search on ... ? eg "0" is only 1 letter and none perform a search on so small a term.

Comment: @tenken I thought that too...just tried a bunch of sites and they all accept that query (`0`), and show all results as the OP is describing. You might be in the realms of bug here since it can be reproduced on a bunch of other sites. Hard to say though

Comment: @tenken I changed in schema.xml <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />

Comment: @Clive by default yes, but I changed solr.LengthFilterFactory in schema.xml